# How does field influence the dimension of vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces

The dimension of a vector space is the number of its basis. And this field is defined
over a field.

I am figuring out how a field influence the dimension of vector space. For example 
$\mathbb{F}[x]$ is finite-dimensional because the degree could approach infinity.

However, $\mathbb{F}_n[x]$ is finite-dimensional since the set of $N+1$ vectors $\{x^n\}^N_{n=0}$ is a basis.

So, a vector space could be finite dimension over a field like the former one however, be infinite dimensional in the later one. Is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, at least if we identify the vector spaces (see below). For example, the dimension of $\mathbb{C}$ over itself is $1$ (this is true for any vector space), the dimension of $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is $2$, and the dimension over $\mathbb{Q}$ is infinite.

Similarly, the splitting field $\mathbb{K}'$ of an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{K}[x]$ of degree $n$ has dimension $n$ over $\mathbb{K}$ but dimension $1$ over itself.

Strictly speaking, the underlying field is part of the data defining a given vector space, so, e.g., $\mathbb{C}$ viewed as a complex vector space is different from $\mathbb{C}$ viewed as a real vector space, despite that the underlying addition operation is the same. (Note that the scalar multiplication maps are, however, different.)